# position of "hello world" text set by me and on the Android virtual device is completely different

Tags: android-virtual-device

I am new to android dev, and I was just trying out some new things. While starting to get a feel of things, I decided to run my basic "hello world" text display application on android virtual device.
But the position which I set for the text (center) and the position in which it is displayed in the AVD is completely different.

I specified everything such as how much padding and margin should be there in order for the text to be aligned center but after running the application , the text is shown in the top left corner . Am I missing something?

Comment: we cant help you as there nothing we can see. Provide the entire xml code along with screenshot of  layout coming in android studio and the one you are getting in avd.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.